# Using Regex Pattern for Money with XML / XSD files

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, schema

first time creating a schema - not sure what the issue is here.

I want to use a regex pattern that accepts an infinite number of digits to the left of a decimal point and only two digits to the right (standard dollar notation) as a custom data type for "price" as it is used in the XML document, however I'm receiving the following pair of errors:

**"cvc-pattern-valid: Value '219.99' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^[0-9]+.[0-9]{2}$' for type 'money'."**

**"cvc-attribute.3: The value '219.99' of attribute 'price' on element 'product' is not valid with respect to its type, 'money'**

Here's the relevant section from my XML file where "price" is returning the error:

```
<product sku="29043" category="audio" isFeatured="no" price="219.99">
    <name>Sennheiser PC350 Gaming Stereo Headset</name>
    <description>Gaming stereo headset, 10-26000Hz, 150ohm, 10-ft cord, noise-cancelling microphone.</description>
    <colors>
      <color>Black</color>
      <color>Red</color>
    </colors>
  </product>
```

Here is my XSD file with the relevant sections:

```
<xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="category" type="section"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="isFeatured" type="yesno"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="price" type="money"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:simpleType name="section">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="audio"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="appliance"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="bathroom"/> 
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="yesno">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="money">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value='^[0-9]+.[0-9]{2}$'/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Any pointers?  Can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 2):

XSD regex patterns require full string match, and `^` and `$` are not parsed as anchors there.

You can use

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="money">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value='[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This matches a string that starts with one or more digits (`[0-9]+`), then has a dot (`\.`, note it should be escaped) and ends with two digits (`[0-9]{2}`).